# How to disable a checkbox column on clicking of another checkbox column in DatagridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewlinkcolumn

I have two ckecboxes (Error and Enable) as under

[image]

If I uncheck "Enable" checkbox, the corrresponding "Error" checkbox will become greyed out.

[image]

I tried like the below but there is no enable or disable property

```
    void dgRulesMaster_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.RowIndex > -1 & e.ColumnIndex == 3)
      {
   var editingCellFormattedValue = Convert.ToBoolean(((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dgRulesMaster.Rows[dgRulesMaster.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[3]).EditingCellFormattedValue);

     if (editingCellFormattedValue == false)
     {
          dgRulesMaster[2, e.RowIndex].ReadOnly = true;
     }
  }    
}
```

Comment: Does your code make it inside of the `if` statement? And is there a `Checked` property for `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, use a custom painting (I love it :), I suppose the Cell should look like Disable when it's ReadOnly, of course it applies only on `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`, here is my code:

```
void dgRulesMaster_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.RowIndex > -1 & e.ColumnIndex == 3)
  {
    var editingCellFormattedValue = Convert.ToBoolean(((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dgRulesMaster.Rows[dgRulesMaster.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[3]).EditingCellFormattedValue);

    if (editingCellFormattedValue == false)
    {
      dgRulesMaster[2, e.RowIndex].ReadOnly = true;
      dgRulesMaster.InvalidateCell(2,e.RowIndex);
    }
  }   
 } 
 //And here is the CellPainting event handler for your dataGridView
 private void dgRulesMaster_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e){
    if (e.ColumnIndex > -1 && e.RowIndex > -1 && 
       dgRulesMaster.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn && dgRulesMaster[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ReadOnly)
        {
            Size checkSize = CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize(e.Graphics, System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal);                
            e.Handled = true;
            e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
            if (e.Value != null)
            {
                CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, new Point(e.CellBounds.X + e.CellBounds.Width / 2 - checkSize.Width / 2, e.CellBounds.Y + e.CellBounds.Height / 2 - checkSize.Height / 2), 
               (bool)e.Value ? System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.CheckedDisabled : System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.UncheckedDisabled);                    
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell' does not contain a definition for 'InvalidateCell' and no extension method 'InvalidateCell' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell'
 could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: sorry again, I've just typed myself and made mistake, that's `DataGridView.InvalidateCell()', it has 'Invalidate(), InvalidateCell(), InvalidateRow()... sorry